# Where can I find good Struts2 tutorial/references for beginners?

Tags: struts2

I am a beginner in Struts2. Can anyone can provide links to video or tutorials on Struts2 and Hibernate with netbeans, to give me a head start in this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing real work with Struts2, the tutorials (and the "Starting Struts2") are not enough, some real books are advisable: "Struts 2 in Action" is nice, and also "Webworks in Action" . Bear in mind that Struts2 has MUCH more in common with Webworks than with Struts.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Struts 2 in action is a good book, but, even better is write a lot of code, practice!

Answer (score 3):

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/getting-started.html

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/home.html